# array variant subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to define an array variant, but while running always meet run-time error 9-subscript out of range. Could anyone please help?
Following is my code

```
Dim wkbNPI As Workbook
Dim wksPT As Worksheet
Dim wksFU As Worksheet

Dim lrw As Long

Set wkbNPI = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksPT = Sheets("Packaging tracking")
Set wksFU = Sheets("FollowUpMaterial")

lrw = wksPT.Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).row
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Dim PTarray As Variant
PTarray = wkbNPI.wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw).Value

Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 7 To UBound(PTarray)
    If PTarray(i, 31) <> 0 Then
        PTarray(i, 32) = wf.IfError(wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 13, False), "")                    'vlookup follow up material
        PTarray(i, 33) = wf.IfError(wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 17, False), "")                      'vlookup follow up material effective out date
    End If
Next i

On Error Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: on which line is the error? What is the value of lrw and what is the value of i when failing if failing inside the For. You can inspect variables using the locals window to check dimensions.

Comment: @JNevill You are correct in principle, but unqualified `Rows.Count` applies to the entire sheet, and total row count is the same on all sheets.

Comment: This line was showing error -object doesn't support this property or method `PTarray = wkbNPI.wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw2).Value`

Comment: That's a rather different error to "subscript out of range". It happens because `wksPT` is your variable containing a sheet, not a part of the `Workbook` class definition, even though the sheet instance referenced by that variable belongs to the `Sheets` collection of the workbook referenced by the `wkbNPI` variable. You're supposed to use it on its own, `wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw).Value`.

Comment: @GSerg I have changed to your code and it still gives a different run-time error 1004- Method 'Range of object' _worksheet' failed

Comment: is lrw zero by any chance? I've never seen anything like `Cells(Rows.Count, "AE")`; usually I see `Range("AE" & Rows.Count)` or `Cells(Rows.Count, 31)`. Not sure if that'll solve the problem though.

Comment: @Brotato `Cells(Rows.Count, "AE")` is valid syntax and the ability to specify columns with a number or a String is part of why I prefer using it whenever possible

Answer (score 1):

Define sheet objects and workbook objects separately.

Try like this.

```
Sub test()
Dim wkbNPI As Workbook
Dim wksPT As Worksheet
Dim wksFU As Worksheet

Dim lrw As Long

Set wkbNPI = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksPT = wkbNPI.Sheets("Packaging tracking") '<~~ set sheet with workbook
Set wksFU = wkbNPI.Sheets("FollowUpMaterial") '<~~ set sheet with workbook

lrw = wksPT.Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Dim PTarray As Variant
PTarray = wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw) '< remove workbook

Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 7 To UBound(PTarray)
    If PTarray(i, 31) <> 0 Then
        PTarray(i, 32) = wf.IfError(wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 13, False), "")                    'vlookup follow up material
        PTarray(i, 33) = wf.IfError(wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 31), wksFU.Range("B:R"), 17, False), "")                      'vlookup follow up material effective out date
    End If
Next i

On Error Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried you code but it still gives a run-time error 1004- Method 'Range of object' _worksheet' failed